# Can I expect a prorated reimbursement from an early termination of my auto insurance policy?

Tags: united-states, car-insurance

If one cancels their insurance policy early during their prepaid coverage period are insurers supposed to credit/reimburse the prorated amount actually utilized of their coverage?

I'm looking to change insurers to find a better rate but for the time it's more convenient to stick with my current insurer for a policy renewal that's right around the corner. In other words I don't have the luxury of time to research policies and need to be covered during that research period. I'm hoping I can renew the policy, and then jump ship early on to a more competitive insurer. Are there any gotchas to doing so, fees to be paid, or any other surprises one might expect that would result in a lesser than prorated amount? Is this true for most forms of insurance?

Comment: We always got reimbursed for the unused portions of paid insurance premiums, and there were never any termination fees or other gotchas.  This is an anecdote, though, not data.

Comment: All auto insurance law in the United States is done at the state level. Please specify the state, because some states may have a time limit, or notice period that others do not have. The state could also specify an administrative fee they can charge, or they might not have a fee at all.